# Compute the homology of the universal covering space of the wedge of two circles and a sphere.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I would like to compute the singular homology groups for the universal covering space of $X = S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2 $.

I have constructed a space, $E$, to represent this universal covering space: Let $E$ be the the $xy-$coodinate axes in $\mathbb{R} ^2$ with a copy of $S ^2$ attached to each integer on the $x-$axis at their north poles.

This space $E$ is simply connected and it covers $X$ by translating all the $S^2$'s to the $S^2$ at the origin and mapping the $x-$axis to the first $S^1$ and the $y-$axis to the second $S^1$ via the standard covering map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1 $.

$E$ is simply connected. So I know $H_0(E) \cong \mathbb{Z} $ and $H_1(E) \cong \pi _1 (E) =0$. However I am not sure how to compute $H_n(E) $ for $n\geq 2$.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. What is the universal covering space of $S^1\vee S^1$?

Comment: the universal cover is a four-valent tree with $S^2$ at each vertex.  $H_2$ is a countable sum of $\mathbb{Z}$s and $H_n=0$ for $n\geq3$

Comment: @yoyo can you remind me what a "four-valent tree" looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The space you’ve constructed isn’t a universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$. Note that at the base point of $X$, the space looks like a sphere attached to the origin of a pair of axes. If your candidate covering space is spheres attached to integers on the axes, those are spheres attached to lines. (I agree that there’s a continuous map from your space to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ in the way you described, but a covering map has to be a local homeomorphism.)

See Section 1.3 of Allan Hatcher’s “Algebraic Topology” for the construction of the universal covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$, which is a kind of “fractal tree” (called a 4-valent tree in the comments). Call this tree $T$. The covering space you want is the tree $T$ with a sphere attached at each node. Here is how you may wish to proceed:

- First show that $T$, the universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$, is contractible (not just simply connected). Construct an explicit homotopy of $T$ to a point.
- Use the homotopy found above to show that the universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ is homotopic to the wedge sum $T \vee \mathop{\bigvee}_{k=1}^\infty S^2$.

This last space is quite straightforward to find the homology of.

Comment: Nice answer, except that there's nothing particularly "fractal" about the tree $T$. The end space of $T$, which is homeomorphic to a Cantor set, could perhaps be regarded as a fractal; but not $T$ itself.

Comment: True, I use the word "fractal" loosely here (hence the quotes), in that the tree exhibits self-similarity.

Comment: Ah, you see, that's the thing, the tree itself has no self-similarity at all. Its self-transformations act on the tree by simplicial isomorphisms, and that kind of action is the opposite of self-similarity.